# Is there a solution to this Unity WebGL build problem?

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl

When doing a WebGL build of a Unity game I'm getting the following errors:

IOException: Access to the path '\?\C:\Users\clint\Unity\Haunted Zombie Rush\Library\BuildPlayerData\Editor' is denied.

Error building player because script class layout might be incompatible between the editor and the player.

I granted 'Everyone' full control of the folder that is saying access denied.

This project uses Unity 2023.1.19f1.
I'm running Windows 11.

Comment: cant say ive had that and i exclusively work in webgl ...  personally, id close unity, delete the contents of library, make sure none of it is in a onedrive area, and then reopen. and note 2023.1.19 was surpased by .20 and theres also 2023.2 out.

Comment: Thank you @BugFinder!  Deleting the contents of the library folder and rebooting Unity fixed the problem.  This is the result of a tutorial that I went through https://hauntedzombierush.z19.web.core.windows.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BugFinder! Deleting the contents of the library folder and rebooting Unity fixed the problem.